# displaying private google calendar in custom website

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I have the *email* and *password* of a *gmail account*, how can i **display** in my website a **private google calendar** ? (readonly will be fine too)

If i use the HTML link or the iframe link, i need to authenticate the user with no interaction from him somehow,

or is there some javascript calendar(like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/)) which can access private calendar?

Or can i insert events in some javascript calendar ?

i am using zend framework and can authenticate and do stuff like

```
    $service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $password, $service);
    $service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
    $calendars = $service->getCalendarListFeed();
...
```

Comment: I think you should make a widget which would send a request on server side and you can handle the events on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar allows to access calendars without authentication with private links. In Google Calendar click the down arrow next to the calendar you want to share and select "Calendar Settings". Then there is a "Private address" section an you will have three links for XML, ICAL and HTML formats. This link contains authentication token.

EDIT: Obviously use of the [private link is discouraged for sharing](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37648). I expect you could achieve the same, if you make you calendar public and use normal share links.

EDIT2: If you don't have the private address option, you probably use Google with a custom domain. Here is [post how to enable it then](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-bugs/msg/aa092ebd547f9fe9).

Comment: yes but for the private html link to work, you need to be logged into gmail, that's my problem

Comment: No, you don't. You need one, if you use normal Calendar Addres. Try this link - do you need to be looged? https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=36rkeh8hkvrkg2o2d6ult7q5s8%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Warsaw&pvttk=8d1261ca5a137d27decd85434d5e3390

Comment: no it works without login, so that is a private calendar? then how come everyone can see it ?

Comment: Yes, it is private calendar, and private normally is not intended for sharing. The private adders contains authorization token (a hex string at the end), without the token it cannot be accessed. Read about it here: http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37648

Comment: while the documentation states that http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=41208 the only url i can get is http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=MYEMAIL@SOMETHING.COMctz=UTC ,i can not use that link unless i make it public, or am logged in with gmail, argh

Comment: i found the problem, i am using a google apps account, while the link only shows for normal gmail accounts, turns out you pay google and get less service than the free ones

Comment: See the link from the second edit - it says how to enable private address if you are using google apps.

Comment: They disabled the private HTML link option :(

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to embed a private calendar into a custom website unless you give the Google user permission or you make the calendar public.

[image]